# Hadoop command to know the default configuration value

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Is there any shortcut or hadoop command to know what is the value that hadoop will use by default when run mapreduce job?  Basically I want to know prior running a hadoop job what are the default values that it will use for  mapred.map.tasks  mapred.reduce.tasks  dfs.block.size  etc  Thanks

Comment: Similarly if we want to know mapred.max.split.size and mapred.min.split.size that my hadoop will use by default, is there a way ? we can use hadoop dfsadmin -safemode get to know if its in safemode or not? Do we have such commands for other configuration values?

Comment: Any suggestions members?